# Result of substring not work when use CASE statement

Tags: postgresql-9.5

Column's type : jsonb

Here table's data:

[image]

Now I want to convert **2.5kg** to **2500**. And remove rest substring.

Here query:

```
select id,
    case when title_en ~ 'kg$' 
    then 
        cast(replace(substring(title_en 
        from 
        (length(title_en) - position(' ' in reverse(title_en)) + 1) -- last space position
        for 
        (position('kg' in title_en)) - (length(title_en) - position(' ' in reverse(title_en)) + 1) -- count of chars to extract
                 ),',','.')::float * 1000 as text)
    else title_en
    end,
weight_qty, options_weight from result_table
```

I converted all column to **text** type.
Here result:

[image]

Nice. It's correct result. Now I need to filter record content **2500** in column **title_en**

I try this (show only **where** clause)

```
weight_qty, options_weight from result_table
where  
title_en ~ '2500'
```

But result is empty.

But if I try with old value (**2.5kg**) than it correct show one record.

```
weight_qty, options_weight from result_table
where  
title_en ~ '2.5kg'
```

Here result:
[image]

Why not work with new value (**2500**) ?